# How to update frame using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created two frames using tkinter. In the first frame named `StarterPage` there is a button that execute the function:

```
estrazioneCanzoni(sp, codice_playlist_piaciute, codice_playlist_non_piaciute)
```

where there is this declaration:

```
global scoreDecisionTree, scoreKnn, scoreRandomForest, scoreKmeans
```

and where I evaluate the previous variables with some values. I have checked that the evaluation of the global variables works printing them using the console.

The button also open the `PageOne` frame. The problem is that `PageOne` frame shows as value for `scoreDecisionTree`, `scoreKnn`, `scoreRandomForest` and `scoreKmeans`: `None`, instead of the actual values that I can see when I print them in the console, not using the tkinter gui. I think the problem is that `PageOne` frame is created at the beginning and never updated. How can I solve it?

```
scoreDecisionTree=None
scoreKnn=None
scoreRandomForest=None
scoreKmeans=None

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.frames["StartPage"] = StartPage(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames["PageOne"] = PageOne(parent=container, controller=self)


        self.frames["StartPage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames["PageOne"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        sp=login()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="ID playlist canzoni piaciute", font = "Times 15")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
        self.entry1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="ID playlist canzoni non piaciute",font = "Times 15")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
        self.entry2.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        def parametri():
            estrazioneCanzoni(sp, self.entry1.get(), self.entry2.get())
            controller.show_frame("PageOne")

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Analizza",
                            command= lambda: parametri())

        button1.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Accuratezza", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, font="Times 12" )
        label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label1.config(text = "Decision tree: {}".format(scoreDecisionTree))
        label2 = tk.Label(self, font="Times 12" )
        label2.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label2.config(text = "Knn: {}".format(scoreKnn))
        label3 = tk.Label(self, font="Times 12" )
        label3.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label3.config(text = "Random forest: {}".format(scoreRandomForest))
        label4 = tk.Label(self, font="Times 12" )
        label4.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label4.config(text = "Kmeans: {}".format(scoreKmeans))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `PageOne` `label.config` calls into a `PageOne.update_globals` method:

```
def update_globals(self):
    self.label1.config(text="Decision tree: {}".format(scoreDecisionTree))
    self.label2.config(text="Knn: {}".format(scoreKnn))
    self.label3.config(text="Random forest: {}".format(scoreRandomForest))
    self.label4.config(text="Kmeans: {}".format(scoreKmeans))
```

and make a `StartApp.update_globals` method which sends method calls to all the frames that need updating when globals change:

```
def update_globals(self):
    frame = self.frames["PageOne"]
    frame.update_globals()
```

Then have `StartPage` call `controller.update_globals()` inside `parametri`:

```
def parametri():
    estrazioneCanzoni(sp, self.entry1.get(), self.entry2.get())
    controller.update_globals()
    controller.show_frame("PageOne")
```

Thus, whenever the `Analizza` button is pressed, `estrazioneCanzoni` changes the globals,
and `controller.update_globals()` handles the setting of the labels in `PageOne`.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont

scoreDecisionTree = None
scoreKnn = None
scoreRandomForest = None
scoreKmeans = None


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(
            family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.frames["StartPage"] = StartPage(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames["PageOne"] = PageOne(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames["StartPage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames["PageOne"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def update_globals(self):
        frame = self.frames["PageOne"]
        frame.update_globals()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        sp = login()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(
            self, text="ID playlist canzoni piaciute", font="Times 15")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
        self.entry1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        label = tk.Label(
            self, text="ID playlist canzoni non piaciute", font="Times 15")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
        self.entry2.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        def parametri():
            estrazioneCanzoni(sp, self.entry1.get(), self.entry2.get())
            controller.update_globals()
            controller.show_frame("PageOne")

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Analizza", command=lambda: parametri())

        button1.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Accuratezza", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, font="Times 12")
        self.label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, font="Times 12")
        self.label2.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.label3 = tk.Label(self, font="Times 12")
        self.label3.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.label4 = tk.Label(self, font="Times 12")
        self.label4.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

    def update_globals(self):
        self.label1.config(text="Decision tree: {}".format(scoreDecisionTree))
        self.label2.config(text="Knn: {}".format(scoreKnn))
        self.label3.config(text="Random forest: {}".format(scoreRandomForest))
        self.label4.config(text="Kmeans: {}".format(scoreKmeans))

def login():
    # just a simple example to allow the program to run
    return 10


def estrazioneCanzoni(sp, a, b):
    # just a simple example to allow the program to run
    global scoreDecisionTree, scoreKnn, scoreRandomForest, scoreKmeans
    scoreDecisionTree, scoreKnn, scoreRandomForest, scoreKmeans = sp, a, b, a+b


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```